# sed and string of data

Tags: sed

I need to print the data starting from the line that matches `Data after AB process=1234 (full 10):` till end of the file.

I tried putting the data in a variable called "value" and using sed as below. However, it gives an error "extra characters at the end of D command.

```
value="Data after AB process=1234 (full 10):"
sed -n ' '$value' ' p datasourcefile.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '/Data after AB process=1234 (full 10):/,$p' file
```

or

```
value='Data after AB process=1234 (full 10):'
sed -n '/'"${value}"'/,$p' file
```

Take a look at: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the second option and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
{ grep -Fm1 'Data after AB process=1234 (full 10):'; cat; } <infile
```

...will work w/ a GNU `grep` and a regular input file.